# Add class to loop iteration php

Tags: php, css

I'm stumped here.

I have six CSS classes that I want to dynamically apply to my loop.

grid1,grid2,grid3,grid4,grid5,grid6

How do I apply that when I run on the 7th iteration it would apply "grid1" and so and so forth? What would be the best way?

Comment: Ok, you can reset the counter when the current index in iteration is a multiple of 7. Another simple way is to use % operator.

Comment: Okay. Do you need any further help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest and imo cleanest way to achieve this would be to use the [Modulo Operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) (`%`) like this:

```
# file test-modulo-counter.php

for ($item = 0; $item <= 17; $item ++) {
    $counter = $item % 6 + 1;
    echo "$item:\tgrid$counter\n";
}
```

In this example 18 items are iterated (`$item`). In each iteration the remainder of the division of `$item` by 6 (the number of your grid elements) is being calculated ([modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)) and 1 added to ensure that `$counter > 0`. The result is being assigned to `$counter`.

You get this result:

```
$ php test-modulo-counter.php 
0:  grid1
1:  grid2
2:  grid3
3:  grid4
4:  grid5
5:  grid6
6:  grid1
7:  grid2
8:  grid3
9:  grid4
10: grid5
11: grid6
12: grid1
13: grid2
14: grid3
15: grid4
16: grid5
17: grid6
```

**bonus code fun:**
You could do it in one line:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 17; $c = $i % 6 + 1, print "grid$c\n", $i ++);
```